# How to execute Completable on Subscribe/Unsubscribe

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

There is my method:

```
public void openWorkshift(WorkshiftSettings workshiftSettings, Subscriber<WorkshiftSettings> subscriber) {
    api.openWorkshift(workshiftSettings)
            .compose(RxOperatorsHelpers.additionalStacktrace())
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> actionsSystem.registerAction(...).await()) // <-
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> actionsSystem.unregisterAction(...).await()); // <-
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(uiScheduler)
            .doOnError(this::handleError)
            .subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

Where `ActionsSystem.registerAction(...)`/`ActionsSystem.unregisterActions(...)` looks like that:

```
public Completable registerAction(OperatorAction action) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> actions.add(action));
}

public Completable unregisterAction(OperatorAction action) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> actions.remove(action));
}
```

As you can see, I use `.await()` to execute `Completable` in flow of source Observable. It feels like wrong solution. **How can I do it more elegant?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Completable`s perform trivial actions, you could just simply inline their code into the `doOnSubscribe` and `doOnUnsubscribe`:

```
        .doOnSubscribe(() -> actions.add(action))
        .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> actions.remove(action))
```

You can avoid `doOnSubscribe` by starting with the completable `andThen` the rest of the `Observable` sequence:

```
actionsSyste.registerAction(...)
.andThen(api.openWorkshift(workshiftSettings)
        .compose(RxOperatorsHelpers.additionalStacktrace())
        .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> actionsSyste.unregisterAction(...).await())
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        .observeOn(uiScheduler)
        .doOnError(this::handleError)
 )
 .subscribe(...)
```

Currently, there is no way to execute a `Completable` when the downstream unsubscribes and no easy way to execute it when the sequence may terminate normally or with an exception.

Comment: Using `doOnSubscribe(...)` seems more clean solution in comparison with wrapping `Observable` into `andThen(observable)`. And I also can't get the result of `api.openWorkshift(...)` in this case.

Comment: Is it normal practice not to use `Observable/Completable/Single/whatever` for trivial actions in "reactive architecture"?

Answer (score 1):

You might make use of `Observable.defer`. This operator delays creating observable until it is subscribed:

```
Observable observable = Observable.defer(() -> {
        actions.add(action);
        api.openWorkshift(workshiftSettings)
}).compose(RxOperatorsHelpers.additionalStacktrace())
    .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
    .observeOn(uiScheduler)
    .doOnError(this::handleError);
```

Then make use of `Subscription`. According to [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/Subscriptions.html#create(rx.functions.Action0)) `Subscription.create()`:

> Creates and returns a Subscription that invokes the given Action0 when unsubscribed.

So basically you need to do:

```
Subscription subscription = Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        actionsSyste.unregisterAction(...);
    }
});    
subscriber.add(subscription);
observable.subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: That's right solution, but it's less elegant that just calling `Completable.await()` :)